# How to calculate np.mean for images of 3D array?

Tags: python, image, keras, mean, np

I want to use mean subtraction and standardization as a normalization for my CNN model. I'm working on Keras classifying images.

However, I don't yet fully understand the difference between using mean subtraction, standardization and simple process such as rescaling images =/255.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834276/numpyzero-mean-data-and-standardization) it was mentioned that there are three ways to do it:

```
np.mean(x) # calculates the mean of the array x
x-np.mean(x) # this is equivalent to subtracting the mean of x from each value in x
x-=np.mean(x) # the -= can be read as x = x- np.mean(x)
```

What I'm currently using is simple rescale:

```
train_data = train_data / 255
```

But my model performance is low. 
So, I decided to change the normalization and use mean subtraction but I don't know how to do it for a 3D array.

Comment: It's the same for a 3D array; the question is just what kind of mean you want to take. For example, you can take the mean along one axis, which will give you a 2D array, or along two axes, which will give you a 1D array, or the mean of everything, which will give you a scalar. Check out the `axis` parameter in the `mean` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do image normalization. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611556).

For your case you want to do normalization by subtracting the mean of your array. You can use the mean of a 3D array along two axis using [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html). It will give you a scalar value that you can then subtract from your original array `x`.

```
train_data = np.random.rand(28,28,3)
mean = np.mean(train_data)
train_data -= mean
```

And if you want to subtract the mean for each channel than you can use `axis` parameter in the `mean` function.

```
mean = np.mean(train_data,axis=(0, 1))
```

This will give mean value for each channel and to subtract mean use as above `train_data-=mean`.

Further you can normalised data by subtracting mean and dividing by its standard deviation. It is used lot in machine learning applications.